# Pb Listing Files and then download with FTPWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I developped a method to download files from a windows ftp server and it run correctly. But when i try to use it to download files from a linux server, i have problems with the FTPWebRequest method : WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory : i catch the exception that no file exist.

Here is the code where i try to get the list of the files :

```
                FtpWebRequest reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://blabla.cnvt.com/files/");
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userId", "password");
                reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
                reqFTP.Proxy = null;
                response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    result.Append(line);
                    result.Append("\n");
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }
```

Note that when i use the ListDirectoryDetails method it works but i can't get correctly my files names.

What can i do to get the files ? 
Apply a regex to the ListDirectoryDetails (but it's not good for the performance) ? 
Is it possible to download all files without to know their name? 
Or  should i use another library  (in this case you know some free library for .NET 4.0)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i have used the ListDirectoryDetails method to get files and i do some treatments : verify the file extensions and split the detail of file to extract only the name.